# unable to connect to corosync-Job for corosync.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: sql-server, linux, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

trying to start pacemaker cluster. I got an error in staring nodes.

```
nodes configuration : ubuntu 18.04
mssql-server 2017 edition
2 nodes are added into /etc/hosts as
localhost node1
192.168.43.64 node2

on running sudo pcs cluster start --all
```

> I get an error : unable to start corosync

I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-availability-group-cluster-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017) exactly. 
As above link i executed pcs cluster destroy.
I tried to create log files into `/var/log/cluster/` folder as said in link. It didn't work.

part of my `corosync.conf` file contains:

```
logging {
    to_logfile: yes
    logfile: /var/log/corosync/corosync.log
    to_syslog: yes
}
```

and error I get at the end:

> Response Code: 400
>   --Debug Response Start-- Starting Cluster... Job for corosync.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See
>   "systemctl status corosync.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>   Error: unable to start corosync
>
> node1: Error connecting to node1 - (HTTP error: 400) node2: Error
>   connecting to node2 - (HTTP error: 400) Error: unable to start all
>   nodes node1: Error connecting to node1 - (HTTP error: 400) node2:
>   Error connecting to node2 - (HTTP error: 400)

I need both the nodes to be connected.
Any help I get would be great and thanks in advance

Comment: Have you configured / disabled your firewall ?